# Python django redirect url on render

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm looking to make a website with the following URL:

```
http://test.com
```

On accessing that URL, django will redirect it to this URL:

```
http://test.com/ABCDE
```

How would I go about this?

I know I can do

```
return render(request, 'websiteHTMLFile.html', {
    'context': RequestContext(request),
})
```

Which will render the `websiteHTMLFile.html` at `http://test.com` but I dont know how to make it redirect to http://test.com/ABCDE

Answer (score 2):

Using [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def yourview(request):
    return redirect('/ABCDE')
```